# How to extract the ABI part from JSON file created in artifacts and create a separate file for it?

Tags: hardhat, abi, unittesting

I have been using the `Hardhat environment` for a while now, and every time I have to provide the `ABI` to the front-end team, I need to copy-paste the `ABI` manually from the `JSON` file, since it contains other useless values which they don't need.

```
{
  "_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1",
  "contractName": "Test",
  "sourceName": "contracts/Test.sol",
  "abi": [...]
}
```

So, my question is if there is a script that I can use that extracts the `ABI` part automatically, and create separate files for these just `ABIs`? Not sure if the question is relevant, but just wanted to try something that can make our lives easier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript questions are not part of Ethereum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a code to extract the ABIs from the artifacts and copy them into a new folder. Let me know if there is a simpler solution:

```
const extractAbi = async () => {
  const mainFolder = "artifacts/contracts/";
  fs.readdirSync(mainFolder).forEach((folder) => {
    if (folder.includes(".sol")) {
      const absolutePath = mainFolder + folder + "/";

      fs.readdirSync(absolutePath).forEach((file: any) => {
        if (!file.includes(".dbg.json")) {
          const finalPath = absolutePath + file;
          const parentDirectory = __dirname.substr(
            0,
            __dirname.lastIndexOf("/")
          );
          const abiFolder = parentDirectory + "/abis";

          try {
            if (!fs.existsSync(abiFolder)) {
              fs.mkdirSync(abiFolder);
            }
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }

          let data: any = fs.readFileSync(finalPath);

          fs.writeFileSync(
            `abis/${file}`,
            JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data).abi)
          );
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A great package to use is [`hardhat-deploy`](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy), which creates *deployment* objects for each deployed contract. These objects contain the abi and the address of any deployed contract and you can export them to json.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I am not able to implement it and get the solution. Can you tell me some more?